# CircularpageIndicator and viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Do we have any circularpageindicator and view pager example or any existing library like I have attached in image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHwrU.png)[image]

[image]

Comment: Product intro. Its called a view pager. The circle you see at the bottom is a Circlepageindicator

Comment: Any existing library ?

Comment: https://github.com/matrixxun/ProductTour. check this if it helps

Comment: I made this indicator... using just `a TextView and a String array` (containing all the combinations of empty and full **Unicode circles**).

Comment: Raghunandan please write your comment as an answer I will mark it as answer.

Comment: And why am I getting negative for my question ?

Comment: Hey Frank, Can you elaborate your answer with some sample code in answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have an array in your `values/arrays.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- Pager position (5 pages) -->
        <string-array name="positions" translatable="false">
            <item>\u25cf \u25cb \u25cb \u25cb \u25cb</item>
            <item>\u25cb \u25cf \u25cb \u25cb \u25cb</item>
            <item>\u25cb \u25cb \u25cf \u25cb \u25cb</item>
            <item>\u25cb \u25cb \u25cb \u25cf \u25cb</item>
            <item>\u25cb \u25cb \u25cb \u25cb \u25cf</item>
        </string-array>

    <!-- ... -->

</resources>
```

Here , `<!-- ... -- >` means you may have some other arrays.

Now, how to set this values in code?

```
// Declare the array (5 positions)
private static String positions[] = new String[5];
// Fill it by getting it from the resource array we prepared earlier
positions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.positions);

// Prepare an index
private static int pIndex = 0;
//Set it's value in code (here it's fixed, but normally it's a counter)
// pInxex range: 0,..., 4
pIndex = 3;

// Find the position holder View
final TextView txtPosition = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtPosition);
// Set its value
txtPosition.setText(positions[pIndex]);
```

Result (pIndex = 3)

[image]